# Oracle count days per month

Tags: sql, oracle, sysdate

I wrote this SQL statement to calculate the days for each month

```
(select count(*) DAYs FROM
    (
     select trunc(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1),'MM') +  level -1 Dates from dual connect by
      level <= ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),1)-1 -  trunc(sysdate,'MM')+1
   ) Where To_char(dates,'DY') NOT IN ('SA','SO'))
```

At the moment this statement ignores Saturdays and Sundays and it calculates the days from the month before the sysdate (June).

June has 22 days without weekends but sadly my statement says it has 23. I found out it includes the 1st July, which is wrong.

Do you know how I can tell my little statement it only calculates the days from the month I want to get not including days from another month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this sort of thing is always going to look not pretty... here's one way, which does it for the entire current year. You can restrict to a single month by adding an additional statement to the where clause:

```
 select to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'y') + level - 1, 'fmMON') as month, count(*)
   from dual
  where to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'y') + level - 1, 'fmDY', 'nls_date_language=english') not in ('SAT','SUN')
connect by level <= trunc(add_months(sysdate, 12), 'y') - trunc(sysdate, 'y')
  group by to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'y') + level - 1, 'fmMON')
```

As I said, not pretty.

Note a couple of things:

- Use of the [`fm` format model modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#i170559) to remove leading spaces
- Explicit use of `nls_date_language` to ensure it'll work in all environments
- I've added 12 months to the current date and then truncated it to the first of January to get the first day of the new year for simplicity
- If you want to do this by month it might be worth looking at the [`LAST_DAY()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions084.htm#SQLRF00654) function

The same statement (using `LAST_DAY()`) for the previous month only would be:

```
 select count(*)
   from dual
  where to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'y') + level - 1, 'fmDY', 'nls_date_language=english') not in ('SAT','SUN')
connect by level <= last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1)) - add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1) + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your inner query (`select trunc(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1),'MM') +  level -1 Dates from dual connect by level <= ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),1)-1 -  trunc(sysdate,'MM')+1`) returns the days of the month plus one extra day from the next month.

Secondly, a simpler query could use the LAST_DAY function which gets the last day of the month.

Finally, use the `'D'` date format to get the day of the week as a number.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM') + ROWNUM - 1, 'D') d
  FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE),'DD'))
) WHERE d BETWEEN 1 AND 5;
```

Comment: `TO_CHAR( DATE, 'D' )` is dependant on the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting - in some territories Monday is not the first day of the week.

Answer (score 1):

Without having to generate all days of the month and then count them:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7352a/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION WORK_DAYS_IN_MONTH(
  dt DATE
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
AS
  first_day DATE   := TRUNC( dt, 'MM' );
  remainder NUMBER := LAST_DAY( dt ) - ( first_day + INTERVAL '27' DAY );
BEGIN
  RETURN 20 + CASE first_day - TRUNC( first_day, 'IW' )
                   WHEN 0 THEN remainder                  -- Monday
                   WHEN 1 THEN remainder                  -- Tuesday
                   WHEN 2 THEN remainder                  -- Wednesday
                   WHEN 3 THEN LEAST( remainder, 2 )      -- Thursday
                   WHEN 4 THEN LEAST( remainder, 1 )      -- Friday
                   WHEN 5 THEN GREATEST( remainder-2, 0 ) -- Saturday
                          ELSE GREATEST( remainder-1, 0 ) -- Sunday
                   END;
END;
//
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS( DATE '2014-12-01', LEVEL ) AS "Month",
       WORK_DAYS_IN_MONTH( ADD_MONTHS( DATE '2014-12-01', LEVEL ) ) AS "# Work Days"
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7352a/2/0)**:

```
|                       Month | # Work Days |
|-----------------------------|-------------|
|   January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |          22 |
|  February, 01 2015 00:00:00 |          20 |
|     March, 01 2015 00:00:00 |          22 |
|     April, 01 2015 00:00:00 |          22 |
|       May, 01 2015 00:00:00 |          21 |
|      June, 01 2015 00:00:00 |          22 |
|      July, 01 2015 00:00:00 |          23 |
|    August, 01 2015 00:00:00 |          21 |
| September, 01 2015 00:00:00 |          22 |
|   October, 01 2015 00:00:00 |          22 |
|  November, 01 2015 00:00:00 |          21 |
|  December, 01 2015 00:00:00 |          23 |
```